# case insensitive aggregation and "include" in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like my aggregations in elasticsearch  to return their values with Capitalization Where Specified, but I'd like to be able to search for the terms in lower case.

Using the aggrations filter I can build an aggregation that looks like:

```
{aggs: {tags: {terms: {field: "tags.name", include: "*some tag*"}}}
```

I'd like the above query to return a match even if the match is "Some Tag". How would I go about that?